# Notation power functions and Neyman-Pearson Lemma part

Tags: probability, probability-theory, notation

Thanks for your attention. I have a question about notation.
The way we define the power function is $B(\theta)=P_{\theta} (X \in  R)$ where $X$ is a random VECTOR, and $R$ is a rejection region. I would like to know if the expression below is correct.

$$B(\theta) = P_\theta (X \in  R) =P(X \in R \mid \theta)= \int_R f(X\mid \theta) \, dx  $$

Also, for the proof of Neyman-Pearson Lemma, we define $\phi(x)=I_R(x)$, or that $\phi$ is a function equal $1$ when $x$ (observed vector of $x$) belongs to $R$, and $0$ otherwise. USING ABOVE NOTATION, if I have the following

$$\int_R \phi(x)f(x \mid \theta) \, dx= \int_R 1 \cdot f(x \mid \theta) + \int_R 0 \cdot f(x\mid\theta)  =B(\theta)$$

I am confused about the middle part of the equality when function $\phi$ equals $0$ because $x$ does not belong to $R$. Is this expression correct? Or how would I even integrate $\int_R 0 \cdot f(x \mid \theta)$ when I am saying that $X$ has to belong to $R$, I would say: "since $X$ does not belong to $R$, the integral limits do not exist?" Or a more general question, what happens when $X$ does not belong to the integration R and I am trying to integrate it:
$$X  \notin R$$
and then I have
$$\int_R f(x\mid\theta)$$
does this equal to zero?

I know it may a silly question, I just want to know the details. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote

> $B(\theta)=P_\theta (X \in  \Theta)$ where [$\,\ldots\,$] $R$ is a rejection region.

It should actually say

> $B(\theta)=P_\theta (X \in R)$ where [$\,\ldots\,$] $R$ is a rejection region.

The random vector $X$ belongs to some space $\mathcal X$ (which may be $\mathbb R^n$ or some subset of $\mathbb R^n$).  You need to write

$$
\int_{\mathcal X} \phi(x)f(x \mid \theta) \, dx= \int_R 1 \cdot f(x \mid \theta) + \int_{\mathcal X\,\setminus\,R} 0 \cdot f(x\mid\theta)  =B(\theta).
$$